# Django is showing tables do not exist in my database

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views, postgresql-9.4

I have a database in postgresql where I've created tables via django models. So, with the model Student, I've created form, view, and template to add data into its table. I am not getting any error when I am submitting the form but when I want to check if the data I've sent are in the Student table, I am getting the error bellow:[image: no such table: pages_student]

Bellow is the proof of the existing of the tables in my DB

[image]
Please find the result of the migrations query

[image: makemigrations and migrate query]
Student models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id=models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=8)
    student_firstname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    student_lastname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    student_dob=models.DateField()
    gender=(('Male','M'),
             ('Female','F'))
    student_gender=models.CharField(choices=gender, max_length=6)
     student_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='E:/MTWEBSITE/massiwatech/website/static/Profile_Pictures', blank=False, null=True)
    student_city=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    student_address=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_telephone=models.CharField(max_length=14)
    student_email=models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

Bellow is the codes of the  view.py file and the database configurations.

```
def student(request):
    form=StudentForm(request.POST or None)  
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form=StudentForm()
    return render(request, "register/student.html",{"form":form})

DATABASES = {
    # 'default': {
    #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'yourdatabasename.db'),
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'MASSIWADB',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '*******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',

    }
}
```

Bellow is the form.py

```
class StudentForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model=Student
        fields=['student_id','student_firstname','student_firstname','student_dob'
        ,'student_gender','student_picture','student_city','student_address',
        'student_telephone','student_email']
```

Please tell me where is the error.

[image: Django's html form]

Comment: add your database configuration

Comment: @shafik, I added the database configuration please check now.

Comment: I'm just wondering in your error screenshot, why its showing in `Exception Location` as `sqllite3` it should be showing db engine `psycopg2`

Comment: try `runserver` again

Comment: @shafik,I was using sqlite3 but I as I was facing this issue, I changed to postgresql.

Comment: I runned the server and the error has disappeared. But still I connot add nothing through the django form. Only through the python shell I can add.

Comment: Form may have another issue. Please specify issue